# Plot Highchart Gauge with JSON Data

Tags: c#, asp.net, highcharts

How do I plot highchart Gauge with JSON Data?

I am working on highchart gauge, I got succes in showing the latest data from the database. I used `JavaScriptSerializer` for that

The code is..

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'gauge',
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBackgroundImage: null,
            plotBorderWidth: 0,
            plotShadow: false
        }, 
//Other char parameter comes here
}


   function (chart) {
            setInterval(function () {

                $.getJSON("S14.aspx", function (data, textStatus) {
                    console.log(data);
                    $.each(data, function (index, wind) {
                        var point = chart.series[0].points[0],
                        newVal = wind;
                        point.update(newVal);
                    });

                });
            }, 3000);
        });
```

The code for JSON is

```
public string chartData1
    {
        get;
        set;

    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<double> _data = new List<double>();
        GetData();
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {

            _data.Add((double)Convert.ToDouble(row["S11"]));

        }
        JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        chartData1 = jss.Serialize(_data);

    }
```

**My JSON looks like**

`[1387204961992.4268,72]`

Well the problem is that the dial of gauge is not moving according to the last values i need to refresh the page for that. I know this is happening because the `GetData` function is being executed only one time. I am stuck here.

How do I get the dial move according to the last values updates in the database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is a bug or something in the `visual studio 2012` . I just paste the entire code on the new `aspx` page it it got working. I have not done anything else I just pasted the code on another page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">


        $(function () {
            $('#container1').highcharts({

                chart: {
                    type: 'gauge',
                    alignTicks: false,
                    plotBackgroundColor: null,
                    plotBackgroundImage: null,
                    plotBorderWidth: 0,
                    plotShadow: false
                },

                title: {
                    text: 'Pressure Meter'
                },

                pane: {
                    startAngle: -150,
                    endAngle: 150
                },

                yAxis: [{
                    min: 0,
                    max: 1000,
                    lineColor: '#339',
                    tickColor: '#339',
                    minorTickColor: '#339',
                    offset: -25,
                    lineWidth: 2,
                    labels: {
                        distance: -20,
                        rotation: 'auto'
                    },
                    tickLength: 5,
                    minorTickLength: 5,
                    endOnTick: false
                }, {
                    min: 0,
                    max: 1000,
                    tickPosition: 'outside',
                    lineColor: '#933',
                    lineWidth: 2,
                    minorTickPosition: 'outside',
                    tickColor: '#933',
                    minorTickColor: '#933',
                    tickLength: 5,
                    minorTickLength: 5,
                    labels: {
                        distance: 12,
                        rotation: 'auto'
                    },
                    offset: -20,
                    endOnTick: false
                }],

                series: [{
                    name: 'Pressure',
                    data: [80],
                    dataLabels: {
                        formatter: function () {
                            var psi = this.y,
                                bar = Math.round(psi / 14.50);
                            return '<span style="color:#339">' + psi + ' psi</span><br/>' +
                                '<span style="color:#933">' + bar + ' bar</span>';
                        },
                        backgroundColor: {
                            linearGradient: {
                                x1: 0,
                                y1: 0,
                                x2: 0,
                                y2: 1
                            },
                            stops: [
                                [0, '#DDD'],
                                [1, '#FFF']
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        valueSuffix: ' psi'
                    }
                }]

            },
        // Add some life
        function (chart) {
            setInterval(function () {

                $.getJSON("S12.aspx", function (data, textStatus) {

                    $.each(data, function (index, wind) {
                        var point = chart.series[0].points[0],
                        newVal = wind;
                        point.update(newVal);
                    });

                });
            }, 3000);
        });
        });


    </script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to place this part of code

```
setInterval(function() {
    $(function() {
    $.getJSON('S12.aspx', function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(val) {
        if (val !== null)
        {
        var point = chart.series[0].points[0];
            point.update(val);
        }
        });
    });
    })
},2000)
```

Inside callback chart, like here: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gauge-speedometer

If you receive any errors,please attach.

Comment: Nop its not working, Gauge is displaying only value 0 .

Comment: Is it possible to reproduce your issue as live demo?

Comment: Well the `S12.aspx` page is in the intranet network not on internet.

Comment: Right, it is possible what is returned by s12.aspx? like json or somehing other?

Comment: Data seems to be correct (http://jsfiddle.net/h6j2p/) but I advice to open console (developer tools) and paste console.log(data), in getJSON() function, then you will know if json is got correctly.

Comment: Can you guide me to any example? i am not much aware about JavaScript. I am using `Visual Studio 2012`

Comment: I mean run example, on browser and use developers tools (F12), enable console and see what console.log returns.

Comment: It is giving Output `LOG:0` `LOG:1` Continuously. I have logged val variable

Comment: Please see the edit for new code. Here I checked thn the json which I am getting is not changing at all. I am getting Continuous response like `LOG: 1387212362728.6291,771` the data in json is not changing at all

Answer (score 2):

In order for the chart to update, the browser somehow needs to request the latest data from the server. There are two ways it can do this:

1. A page refresh - the whole page is fetched again, with the latest data.
2. An Ajax request. This makes a request for just the data, without re-loading the entire page.

I presume you would like to update the chart without reloading the entire page. In order do to this, you need to find out about making ajax requests using jquery.

The highcharts site has some resources which will help you (e.g. http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/preprocessing-live-data). You need to learn how to make an ajax call in javascript, and use the returned data to update your chart. You will also need to write the server side part which returns the ajax data. The example given is in php, but it should be fairly straight forward to do something similar in asp.net.